# Lambda KeyError when send request from Postman

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, postman

Trying to test a function that accepts input from a json object. When I run this in the lambda console as a test it works fine, but sending from Postman I get a KeyError. Here is the information:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Extract the input parameter from the event object
    print(event)
    input_parameter = event['inputParameter']

    # Extract the fields from the input parameter
    field1 = input_parameter['field1']
    field2 = input_parameter['field2']
    field3 = input_parameter['field3']

    # Do something with the fields
    result = field1 + " " + field2 + " " + field3

    # Return the result as the response
    return result
```

Test I send that's successful from Lambda console: (This is also the same body I send from Postman)

```
  "inputParameter": {
    "field1": "Name",
    "field2": "Date",
    "field3": "Title"
  }
}
```

Error from cloudwatch and the output of print(event)

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'inputParameter'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in lambda_handler
    input_parameter = event['inputParameter']
```

Console print of event:

```
{'inputParameter': {'field1': 'Name', 'field2': 'Date', 'field3': 'Title'}}
```

Comment: How are you sending anything from Postman to the lambda? How is the lambda reachable? ApiGateway? Function URL? Do you actually send an `invoke`? Your last snippet claims that is ***exactly*** what `print(event)` outputs? If that were the case the code would not fail.

Comment: Using the public URL of the Lambda and configured postman to post using header raw JSON. 

This is the function logs from running the lambda locally. And I agree that I would think that it would be successful as well.

`
Function Logs
START RequestId: 90f6aef4-0c65-47fe-b0f4-fa7d1b1418c5 Version: $LATEST
{'inputParameter': {'field1': 'Name', 'field2': 'Date', 'field3': 'Title'}}
END RequestId: 90f6aef4-0c65-47fe-b0f4-fa7d1b1418c5
REPORT RequestId: 90f6aef4-0c65-47fe-b0f4-fa7d1b1418c5 Duration: 0.84 ms Billed Duration: 1 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB
`

Comment: A Lambda does not have a public URL, a Lambda is not just callable from Postman. Either you have an API Gateway or using a Function URL (which is a dedicated feature to get a URL). Anyway: time for you to do some debugging, maybe you are invoking an old version of the lambda, try changing the code and see if that change is reflected in the invocation, try printing the keys of the dictionary before accessing it, try printing the type of the event, ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this ?

```
import json
import logging



logger = logging.getLogger()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Extract the input parameter from the event object
    logger.info('Received event: ' + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    data = json.loads(event["body"])    

    input_parameter = data['inputParameter']

    # Extract the fields from the input parameter
    field1 = input_parameter["field1"]
    field2 = input_parameter["field2"]
    field3 = input_parameter["field3"]

    # Do something with the fields
    result = field1 + " " + field2 + " " + field3

    # Return the result as the response
    return result
```